# Symfony form validation basic form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a user entity class like this:
     namespace AppBundle\Entity;

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OneToOne;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert; 

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="clients")
*/
class Clients
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
   private $id;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
    * @Assert\NotBlank(
    *      groups={"registration"}, 
    *      message = "Il campo nome non può essere vuoto."
    * )
    */
    private $name;
```

Then, i have a ClientsType like this:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ClientsType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    public function getName() {
        return "Clients";
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Clients',
        'validation_groups' => array('registration'),
        ));
    }

}
```

And i my controller:

```
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

        $client = new Clients();

        $form = $this->createForm(ClientsType::class, $client);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $data = $form->getData();
        print_r($data);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            echo "yes";
        }
            else{
            echo "no";
        }

        die();
    }
```

I my view there are a simple html form.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{last_name}}" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nome">
```

The problem is if i send or not "name" i receive always "no"...

Thank you...Fabio.

Comment: What errors does the form report (using `getErrors()` or `getErrorsAsString()` on the `$form` object)?

Comment: With "$res = $form->getErrors();  print_r($res);" i receive an loooooong response (with some objects...i think more of 2000 lines...without print_r is empty an string). If i use "$form->getErrorsAsString()" i receive "Attempted to call an undefined method named "getErrorsAsString" of class "Symfony\Component\Form\Form".". Thank you!

Comment: I try with $string = (string) $form->getErrors(true, false); but i receive an empty string... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that form is not validated correctly, because input name in template is wrong, so form is not filled with post data. Try to change `name="name"` to `name="Clients[name]"` or transmit your form to template `$form->createView()` and output this element as `{{ form_widget(form.name) }}`

Comment: Hi. I have change my form in                                         

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Nome*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{last_name}}" id="name" name="Clients[name]" placeholder="Nome">
    </div>

But not working...i use for test now simply if ($form->isSubmitted()) and the result is false...thank you :(

Comment: print_r outputs post data? To see errors add this code `foreach($form->getErrors(true) as $error) echo $error->getMessage()."<br/>\n";` after `echo "no";`

Comment: I have used $form->createView() and now my validation's work fine! Thank you!